# Enable jQuery ui in asp.net MVC web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an `asp.net mvc` application in `Visual Studio 2013`. I have a problem when using `jQuery UI` tools.
I have the following scripts in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/1.7.2.jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

when I try to use `datepicker()` :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('.rDate').datepicker();
    });
</script>

 @Html.TextBox("date", new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), new { @class=".rDate"})
```

I get the the error: `JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'`

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I think `jquery UI js file not included in the page`. But why you are referring minified & uncompressed version. Use either one

Comment: See the viewsource of the page in firefox and check how  many jQuery &  jQuery UI files referenced. It looks like you are referring multiple times. Also click on each link and see whether the file content is loaded or `404`

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan, I checked the links, they work. I'd be so grateful if you could provide a demo project where datepicker works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Use minified version of Jquery and Jquery UI and remove repeated script references.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/8Nyy7/

Comment: it didn't help. And Js files links work. Could you please provide any sample project, where datepicker works?

Comment: @GyuzalRakhmayeva, I have added demo in my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. And I found the reason, I needed to remove @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")